# Foundation top-bar-section not responsive when changing from small to large screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Following is the html which I am using:

```
<div class="fixed contain-to-grid">
        <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <h1><a href="#">Name</a></h1>
                </li>
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
                    <a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <ul class="right">
                    <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#photo">Photos</li>
                    <li><a href="#video">Videos</li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

By default, it looks like this:

```
                                                       Home Photos Videos Blog Contact
```

When I am decreasing the size of my browser, it works fine and at the smallest, it turns into a hamburger menu. 
But when I increase the size back to normal, the li tags don't line up as usual.
They appear something like this:

```
                                                                       Home     Photos
                                                                       Videos   Blog
                                                                       Contact
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known responsive-issues with foundation's top-bar.
But your top-bar looks very simple. Could work for you.
First try if **fixing your html-markup** eliminates the problem. You have missing `</a>`-tags.

See:

```
                <li><a href="#photo">Photos</li>
                <li><a href="#video">Videos</li>
                <li><a href="#blog">Blog</li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</li>
```